# Can I use a callback with .submit in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, callback

I'm trying to prevent a return false or undefined from the submit handler. I only want to return a value after the async results come back from google maps. Is this possible? My objective is to wait for google map results to come back before I go to my controller.

```js
$('form').submit(function (e) {
        
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = $('#SearchQuery').val();
        
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                return false;
            } else {
                $("#latitude").val(results[0].geometry.location.G);
                $("#longitude").val(results[0].geometry.location.K);
                
                alert("Geocode successful");
                return true;
            }
        });
        //don't let anything get returned here, is a callback needed?
    });
```

Comment: Those `return`'s inside geocode success aren't doing what you think they are. They do not return to the outer function. Also, geocode request is asynchronous so even if they were doing what you want them to, it would be too late.

Answer (score 0):

The use of your `return` inside a closed callback does not return to the outer submit callback. So basically there is nothing preventing the form submitting without the geocoding being done

What you could do is prevent the jQuery submit event and within the geocode success submit the form through native javascript submit which does not trigger the jQuery version

```
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

 $('form').submit(function (e) {
     // cancel the event to prevent immediate submit
     e.preventDefault();

     var form = this;
     var address = $('#SearchQuery').val();

     geocoder.geocode({
         'address': address
     }, function (results, status) {
         if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);

         } else {
             $("#latitude").val(results[0].geometry.location.G);
             $("#longitude").val(results[0].geometry.location.K);

             alert("Geocode successful");

             // do submit through native submit
             form.submit();

         }
     });

 });
```